# Trouble with unhandled exceptions

Tags: java

I have two methods. Method A calls method B. I cannot change the exceptions of neither (homework demands). However, the 2 exceptions mean the exact same thing, so when I call method B on A, I already know that B's exception is not getting thrown. However, I still get the "unhandled exception" error from Eclipse. How can I avoid it?

Here are the methods

```
 public void createProfile(Profile user) throws PEException {
    Vector<Profile> p = new Vector<Perfil>();
    try{
        if (repository.search(user.getUsername()) == null) {
            repository.register(user); //error on this line when I call the method on main
        }

        else {
        throw new PEException(user.getUsername());
        }
    }   catch (PEException e){
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }
}


public void register(Profile user) throws UJCException {
    try {
        if (this.search(user.getUsername()) == null) {
            this.users.add(user);

        }

        else {
            throw new UJCException(user.getUsername());
        }
    } catch (UJCException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I MUST NOT change the definitions of the methods (I can't throw UJCException on createProfile). Thanks in advance

Comment: is method A createProfile and method B register??? please clarify and show us method A and method B you are talking about

Comment: If you're declaring these exceptions to be thrown, why are you catching them...?

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz yes, it is as you said. I thought it was clear, sorry. I can't change their exception, but if I call one on another, I get an unhandled exception error.

Comment: Can you please put a comment on the specific line which Eclipse is highlighting as the error?

Comment: @Makoto I honestly don't know. It's just the syntax I've seen being used. What do you recommend?

Comment: @gparyani Done. The error is "Unhandled exception type UJCException"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be throwing the exceptions and then catching them inside the same method. That defeats the purpose of throwing the exception in the first place. the methods which calls your 2 methods should expect nothing (void) or the exception in the event that something went wrong. Make sure your methods `createProfile()` and `register()` can actually throw their exception so methods calling them can catch the exception and do whatever it is they need to when the exception is thrown.

```
public void createProfile(Profile user) throws PEException {
    Vector<Profile> p = new Vector<Perfil>(); //not being used...

    if (repository.search(user.getUsername()) == null) {
        try{
            repository.register(user);
        }catch(UJCException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new PEException(user.getUsername());
        }
    }
    else {
        throw new PEException(user.getUsername());
    }
}


public void register(Profile user) throws UJCException
{
    if (this.search(user.getUsername()) == null) {
        this.users.add(user);
    }
    else {
        throw new UJCException(user.getUsername());
    }
}
```

Now when you call these methods wrap the call in a try catch and catch the appropriate exception depending on which method was called

Comment: 1. This doesn't solve the initial problem. It still gives the "unhandled exception type UJCException". 2. I have to treat the exception inside the method, because the method createProfile will only be called on main. I know this defeats the purpose, as I could just use the code of the exception instead of throwing it, but the teacher demands that we use the exceptions. ps: thanks, I didn't see the vector not being used.

Comment: @MarcosMartin fixed it, sorry i missed the inner exception inside createProfile

Comment: the only way you can throw the UJCException is if it's a sub-clas of PEException